# A property of measure-generating function

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, solution-verification

I'm reading about measure-generating function (page 28) in *Analysis III* by Amann/Escher

---

Let $F: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be **increasing** and **continuous from the left**. We say that $F$ is a measure-generating function. If $\lim _{x \rightarrow-\infty} F(x)=0$ and $\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} F(x)=1$, we also say $F$ is a (probability) distribution function. If $F$ is a measure-generating function, we set
$$
\nu_F([a, b)):=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}
F(b)-F(a), & a<b, \\
0, & a \geq b,
\end{array}\right.
$$
for $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$. Because $F$ is increasing, $\nu_F$ is an increasing map into $\mathbb{R}$ from the set of intervals of the form $[a, b)$ with $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$.

**3.5 Proposition** Suppose $F$ is a measure-generating function, and for $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ let $\mu_F^*(A):=\inf \left\{\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \nu_F\left(I_j\right) ; I_j=\left[a_j, b_j\right), a_j, b_j \in \mathbb{R}\right.$ with $\left.A \subset \bigcup_{j=0}^{\infty} I_j\right\}$.
Then $\mu_F^*$ is an outer measure on $\mathbb{R}$, the Lebesgue-Stieltjes outer measure arising from $F$. For $-\infty<a<b<\infty$, we have $\mu_F^*([a, b))=F(b)-F(a)$.

---

The main ingredient to prove $\mu_F^*([a, b))=F(b)-F(a)$ is the following lemma, i.e.,

> **Lemma:** Let $F:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be non-decreasing and left continuous. Assume $[a, b) \subset \bigcup_{j=0}^\infty [a_j, b_j)$. Then
> $$
> F(b) - F(a) \le \sum_{j=0}^\infty [F(b_j) - F(a_j)].
> $$

Previously, I proved a [weaker version](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4538136/let-f-be-non-decreasing-and-a-b-subset-bigcup-i-1n-a-i-b-i-then) of this lemma. That version is weaker and thus does not require the assumption of left continuity. Could you have a check if my below attempt on this lemma is fine or contains logical mistakes?

**My attempt:** WLOG, we assume $[a_j, b_j) \cap [a, b) \neq \emptyset$ for $j \in \mathbb N$, so there are $a'_j < b'_j$ such that $[a'_j, b'_j) := [a_j, b_j) \cap [a, b)$ for $j$. Clearly, $[a, b) = \bigcup_{j=0}^\infty [a'_j, b'_j)$. Because $[a'_j, b'_j) \subset [a_j, b_j)$ and $F$ is non-decreasing, we have $F(b'_j) - F(a'_j) \le F(b_j) - F(a_j)$. It suffices to show that
$$
F(b) - F(a) \le \sum_{j=0}^\infty [F(b'_j) - F(a'_j)].
$$

WLOG, we assume that $a'_j \le a'_{j+1}$ for all $j$. Let $c_0 := a'_0$ and $d_0 := b'_0$. Clearly, $a'_1 \le d_0$. Let $c_1 := d_0$ and $d_1 := \max \{ d_0, b'_1\}$. Recursively, we have $a'_{j+1} \le d_j$ for all $j$. Let
$$
c_{j+1} := d_j \quad \text{and} \quad d_{j+1} := \max \{ d_j, b'_{j+1}\} \quad \forall j.
$$

[image]

As shown in above figure, we have $F(b'_j) - F(a'_j) \ge F(d_j) - F(c_j)$ for all $j$. Also, we have a sequence
$$
a = c_0 < d_0 = c_1 < d_1= c_2< \cdots <d_{j-1}= c_j < d_j = \cdots,
$$
and $[a, b) = \bigcup_{j=0}^\infty [c_j, d_j)$. By construction,
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n [F(d_i) - F(c_i)] = F(d_n)- F(c_0) = F(d_n)-F(a).
$$

We have
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=0}^\infty [F(b'_j) - F(a'_j)] &\ge \sum_{j=0}^\infty [F(d_j) - F(c_j)] \\
&= \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{j=0}^n [F(d_j) - F(c_j)] \\
&= \lim_{n\to \infty} [F(d_n)-F(a)].
\end{align}
$$

Clearly, $d_n \nearrow b$ as $n \to \infty$. Because $F$ is left-continuous, we have $\lim_n F(d_n) = F(b)$. This completes the proof.